# Swift : Unexpectedly found nil

Tags: swift, class, crash, option-type

This code is causing my application to crash and I can't figure out a way to fix it. The error is : **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Any idea how I can fix it? The two lines I'm returning in my createCharacters() function is whats causing the crash:

```
class NACharacters {

var featuredImage : UIImage!

init(featuredImage: UIImage){

    self.featuredImage = featuredImage

}

static func createCharacters() -> [NACharacters]{

    return[
        //THE TWO LINES BELOW CAUSE THE CRASH
        NACharacters(featuredImage: UIImage(named: "Diplo Squad")!),
        NACharacters(featuredImage: UIImage(named: "StopIcon")!)
    ]
  }
}
```

**Solution**: I simply needed to delete the space between "Diplo" and "Squad". It seems this was returning nil.

Comment: Are you sure `Diplo Squad` and `StopIcon` are spelled correctly?

Comment: They are spelt correctly! Thats why this is troubling me, I'm not sure why its nil. @kennytm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if your images "Diplo Squad" und "StopIcon" exist.

(You may need to remove the space in the first image name)

**At least one of these UIImage(name: "...") calls returns nil** and that's probably the crash reason.

Comment: HAHA wow, that was the issue. I simply removed the space between "Diplo Squad". Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that could be nil lines are in the UIImages. check that they exist in your projectNavigator or assets.